# Remove extra 0 in front of numeric month

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a `df` with a column which has dates stored in `character` format, for which I want to extract the months. For this I use the following:

```
mutate(
    
    Date = as.Date(
      
      str_remove(Timestamp, "_.*")
      
      ),
    
    Month = month(
      
      Date, 
      
      label = F)
    
  )
```

However, the October, November and December are stored with an extra zero in front of the month. The `lubridate` library doesn't recognise it. How can I adjust the code above to fix this? This is my `Timestamp` column:

```
c("2021-010-01_00h39m", "2021-010-01_01h53m", "2021-010-01_02h36m", 
"2021-010-01_10h32m", "2021-010-01_10h34m", "2021-010-01_14h27m"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert the values to date and use `format` to get months from it.

```
format(as.Date(x, '%Y-0%m-%d'), '%b')
#[1] "Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct"
```

`%b` gives abbreviated month name, you may also use `%B` or `%m` depending on your choice.

```
format(as.Date(x, '%Y-0%m-%d'), '%B')
#[1] "October" "October" "October" "October" "October" "October"

format(as.Date(x, '%Y-0%m-%d'), '%m')
#[1] "10" "10" "10" "10" "10" "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be use `strsplit` to extract the second element:

```
month.abb[readr::parse_number(sapply(strsplit(x, split = '-'), "[[", 2))]
```

which will return:

```
#"Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct" "Oct"
```

data:

```
c("2021-010-01_00h39m", "2021-010-01_01h53m", "2021-010-01_02h36m", 
  "2021-010-01_10h32m", "2021-010-01_10h34m", "2021-010-01_14h27m"
) -> x
```